# Drive letter conflict between logical drives and mapped network drives

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mappeddrive

After a reboot, one of my servers seems to be sharing a drive letter between a logical drive array and a network location.[image]

`F:\` and `G:\` are (and were prior to the reboot) logical drive arrays. However, I believe that due to a power issue (which was the cause for the reboot), the letters were reassigned automatically.

How can I change the drive letters of these network locations so that my logical drives can use `F:` and `G`: again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to remove the network drives, and then remap them to a different letter.  [I favor the command line, so, I'd use the `net use` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx).

From a command prompt or PowerShell:

```
net use f: /delete
net use g: /delete
net use n: \\ComputerName\ShareName /persistent:yes
net use o: \\OtherComputerName\OtherShareName /persistent:yes
```

(I'd use persistent mappings since you seem to use them, and you'll need or want to reboot for the next step.)

[Once that's done, you can change the drive letters of your physical drives with `diskpart` or with the Disk Management tool under Computer Management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757491%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), and you'll be warned that some programs might not work correctly until a reboot.